# Kubernetes dashboard error using service account token

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I have a Kubernetes cluster with various resources running fine. I am trying to get the Dashboard working but getting the following error when I launch the dashboard and enter the service-account token.

> persistentvolumeclaims is forbidden: User
>   "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard" cannot list
>   resource "persistentvolumeclaims" in API group "" in the namespace
>   "default"

It does not allow the listing of any resources from my cluster (persistent volumes, pods, ingresses etc). My cluster has multiple namespaces.

This is my service-account yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: k8s-test # replace with your preferred username
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: dashboard-admin # replace with your preferred username
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: dashboard-admin # replace with your preferred username
  namespace: kube-system
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

---

### FIX: Create a Role Binding for the cluster role.

This should fix the problem:

```
kubectl delete clusterrole cluster-admin
kubectl delete clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard 
kubectl create clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard
```

The above command will create a role binding that gives all permissions to all resources.

---

### Run the Proxy:

```
kubectl proxy
```

---

### Check the DashBoard: Please check the URL and port provided by kubectl

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#!/persistentvolume?namespace=default
```

---

### More info: Cluster role:

- You can check out the 'cluster-admin' role by:

  ```
  kubectl edit clusterrole cluster-admin
  ```

The problem here is that the serviceaccount 'kubernetes-dashboard' does not have 'list' permissions for the resource 'persistentVolumeClaims'.

Comment: We shouldn't delete the cluster-admin role, as this is needed when we create the clusterrolebinding. Otherwise, this answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [Web UI (Dashboard)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/) documentation from Kubernetes.

> ### Deploying the Dashboard UI
>
> The Dashboard UI is not deployed by default. To deploy it, run the following command:
>
> ```
> kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-beta4/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
> ```

From your `yaml` I can see that you specified them for namespace `kube-system` but dashboard is trying to list resources from namespace `default`, at least that's what is says in your error message.

Also it seems your `yaml` is also incorrect for `ServiceAccount` `name`, as in the file you have `k8s-test` and error message says it's using `kubernetes-dashboard`.